# Google cloud print reports document missing

Tags: java, android, uri, google-cloud-print

I'm building an app that has to print a file. I want to use Google cloud print but it keeps saying the file is missing.

The app creates a pdf using iText. This part works, Adobe reader can show it on my phone. Then I run this:

```
public static final String FILE_URI = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/pdfFile.pdf";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(FILE_URI);

Intent printIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
printIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "pdf");
printIntent.putExtra("title", "pdfFile");
startActivity(printIntent);
```

It launches the print activity, you can log in to your google account but when you press print it says document missing. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the following:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(FILE_URI);
```

and

```
printIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "pdf");
```

use:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/output.pdf"));
```

and

```
printIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
```

It works :)

Comment: accepted even though it's 9 months late and I used another print api. this might help someone.

Comment: Done trying all the above things.. Still getting the same issue of Document Missing. Can some body get help me on this..